# Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'ctl00'. Remove one definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to create a RadGrid with SqlDataSource declaratively and there is need to update the Grid with database records from Server side too.

The sample code is given below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="spSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iTomsConnectionString %>">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Id" SessionField="Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Name" SessionField="Name" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="grvUpdate" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal"
        CellPadding="0" BorderWidth="0px" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" Skin="skn_RadGrid"
        SkinsDir="|CurrentTheme|/" SkinsPath="|CurrentTheme|/"
        Width="382px" CellSpacing="0">
        <MasterTableView
            AllowPaging="true"
            PageSize="15"
            EditMode="PopUp"
            CommandItemDisplay="Top"
            AllowFilteringByColumn="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id">

            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" DataType="System.Int64" FilterControlAltText="Filter Id column" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" UniqueName="Id">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" UniqueName="Name">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn> 
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" UniqueName="Amount">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                   
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn DataTextField="Reject" HeaderText="Reject" SortExpression="Reject" Text="Reject Button" UniqueName="Reject" CommandName="Reject"></telerik:GridButtonColumn> 
            </Columns>

            <EditFormSettings>
                <EditColumn InsertImageUrl="Update.gif" UpdateImageUrl="Update.gif" CancelImageUrl="Cancel.gif"></EditColumn>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>


    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

How can I do Databind without the error as mentioned in the title of this Query in ASP.Net Server code as well as have SqlDataSource to retrieve/update/delete records?

The Server side code in page_load is given below

```
grvUpdate.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
grvUpdate.DataBind();
```

Comment: sounds like the error message is pretty self explanatory remove one or the other..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to implement both methods simultaneously. And the solution is given below.

```
grvUpdate.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
grvUpdate.DataSourceID = String.Empty;
grvUpdate.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

1. Assign your data source control Id to the property, `DataSourceID`, which in your case, should be `DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1"`. This approach uses declarative data source controls and binds data to the grid declaratively. (No extra coding needed)
2. Add `NeedDataSource` event and assign your data source in the code behind, which in your case, should be done like this

Method 1

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="spSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iTomsConnectionString %>">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Id" SessionField="Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Name" SessionField="Name" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<telerik:RadGrid ID="grvUpdate" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    //...
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Method 2

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grvUpdate" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="grvUpdate_NeedDataSource">
    //...
</telerik:RadGrid>

protected void grvUpdate_NeedDataSource(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    grvUpdate.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; // assume ds already exists in the scope
}
```

Please refer to this doc for more topics and details on data-binding of RadGrid:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-binding/understanding-data-binding/telerik-radgrid-data-binding-basics